# Closing main scraping pipeline but keeping image download till it finishes in scrapy

Tags: python, exception, scrapy, pipeline

*Any idea on how to give top priority to the image downloading pipeline in scrapy, or stopping the crawling pipeline without killing the rest?*

#### My goal

I'm coding a crawler using **scrapy**'s spiders. My goal is to crawl through pages and once a condition is met (the scraped update date is older than a parameter), closing the crawling process. But **I don't want the image download pipeline to be closed before finishing it's job**.

So far achieved things are:

- All data except images is stored correctly and the spider closes gracefully.
- Images get downloaded (so the pipeline works) but not all of them.

Problem: Some pages don't get their images downloaded. The "images_urls" fields are filled but "images" field is empty. I suspect this is because the main data scraping pipeline "goes first" and when it's closed it kills the image pipeline.

#### Simplified implementation

I'm summerizing the code in this lines so you can check some important parts.

- mySpider_spider.py --> `raise CloseSpider("Date has been reached")` Closing the scraping pipeline.

Images being correctly downloaded until exception:

- myspider_settings.py --> `ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}`
- main.py --> `process.setting["IMAGES_STORE"] = pathFromArguments` so I can parameterize the output.
- items --> `image_urls = scrapy.Field()` and `images = scrapy.Field()` inside mySpider class.
- mySpider_spider.py --> `#Stores url in image_urls and yields correctly`
- pipelines.py

```
class itemScrapingPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

PD: First post ever here, so I appreciate advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you can add priority to pipelines easily like this:

In settings file give ImagePipeline a higher number than other pipelines. This will assure you download the images right after you **scraped** that page.

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 301,
    'scrapy_redis.pipelines.RedisPipeline': 300}
```

But in order to scrape pages in cronological order you will need to change the pile and use it as a FIFO pile. You can do this in settings again (with this format "DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1"), or give it a value before starting the crawler like I did in my main.py:

```
process.settings["DEPTH_PRIORITY"] = 1
process.settings["SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE"] = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
process.settings["SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE"] = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
```

All three lines are recommended to get it to work.